# Git add does not add all files

Tags: git, netbeans-7

I have project that consists of 8758 files. When I add them to my git it only recognizes 884 objects. When I run `git add .` or `git add -A` or even with `-v` it outputs nothing, but when running add from within Netbeans it displays: "Git command returned with the following error:" (which i never see from the commandline :-s)

`Java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/symfony/vendor/assetic (Is a directory)`

Git is right, assetic is a directory, but why should that be a problem? I think it means something else...?

**Updates**

- The directory is not blank.
- Maybe, (probably) this is the problem.
  the assetic directory contains a own .git. It is not an option to
  remove versioning from that directory.

Comment: FWIW, I would trust the commandline way more than any integrated client.

Comment: @grapefrukt i agree however only the gui gave some kinda of information. The commandline gives nothing.

Comment: Check your git version. Also, check if you leave out some dirs in your .gitignore file.

Comment: How would the git version be relevant?

Comment: Git version is 1.7.5.4 and i have no .gitignore

Comment: from the command line you can also try `add -u` which will add untracked files

Comment: Are you aware that git doesn't track empty directories? Could that be related to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said that the one below is a git repo, that's why it won't be tracked - git won't track another git repo inside itself directly. However, you can accomplish this with the use of [`git submodule`](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).